# Understanding "That's just being down the pub"

Tags: british-english, slang

what does "That's just being down the pub" means in this sentence from the passage:

Sandy:  Come on. You're a philosopher. You like arguments. Show me your stuff.

John: Philosophy is more than liking an argument. That's just being down the pub.

Sandy: You see? We're up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John is saying that philosophy is more than merely liking to have an argument or debate, which is what many people like doing "down the pub" (while at the pub).